# Select different results from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pdo

I've the following structure in the **post** table (example):

```
id | id_author | content | date | ft
1  | 1         | hi!     | 2016 | 2
2  | 1         | hello!  | 2016 | 3
3  | 1         | welcome | 2016 | 1
4  | 1         | test!   | 2016 | 2
```

and I've the `query`:

```
SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7
```

But, I need too, to `select` the posts with your respective `ft` with `LIMIT 4`. Like this:

```
SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' and ft = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4

SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' and ft = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4

SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' and ft = 3 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4
```

I could to do the "filter" of `ft` with a `foreach`, for example:

```
foreach($query as $ex) {
    switch($ex["ft"]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But, my first `query` need to have `LIMIT 7` and the `querys` realtives to `ft` need to select the last 4 results from **all** posts.

How to do this without having to do multiples `querys`?

**EDIT**:

I need to show the last 7 posts (general) in one `div`, the last 4 posts with images (`ft = 1`) in another `div`, the last 4 posts with mentions (`ft = 2`) in another `div` and the last 4 posts with hashtags (`ft = 3`) in another `div`.

Comment: What if you use the `IN` clause? Like this: `SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' and ft IN {1,2,3} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4` Is this what you want? Let me know.

Comment: Please give your expected output.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @Igor, I think you could benefit from creating a stored procedure (SP) in this situation. Because this will not give you what you want: `SELECT id, id_author, content, date, ft FROM post where id_author = '$author' and ft IN {1,2,3} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7` Because if `ft=1` returns 7 rows then the query is done ignoring the rest. I suggest you use an SP.

Comment: Yeah, @pablo-rivas if I use `IN` The results will be with `LIMIT 7`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the `UNION` operator.

```
SELECT
    'General' AS post_type,
    id,
    id_author,
    content,
    date,
    ft
FROM
    Post
WHERE
    id_author = '$author'
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 7
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Image' AS post_type,
    id,
    id_author,
    content,
    date,
    ft
FROM
    Post
WHERE
    id_author = '$author' AND
    ft = 1
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Mentions' AS post_type,
    id,
    id_author,
    content,
    date,
    ft
FROM
    Post
WHERE
    id_author = '$author' AND
    ft = 2
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Hashtags' AS post_type,
    id,
    id_author,
    content,
    date,
    ft
FROM
    Post
WHERE
    id_author = '$author' AND
    ft = 3
ORDER BY
    id DESC
LIMIT 4
```